# iOS app crashes on device after a few days

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I developed a swift framework to use in other projects, and I can use it properly, but a few weeks ago, I had some trouble with my apple certificates, so I revoked/recreated them all and updated my framework, rebuilding it with the new provisioning profiles.

This is when the problems started. Any app that I create using that framework, when run from the device, starts crashing on launch a few days later (ranging from 1 to 4/5 days) with the error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3FC2DC5C-A908-42C4-8508-1320E01E0D5B/Stylist.app/Stylist
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/blablalba/testapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/blablalba/testapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
>   (lldb)

I can temporarily fix the error by opening the console, running the commands

> rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
>
> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
>
> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

And then redeploying to the device.
The problem is that the app starts crashing ON THE DEVICE itself, not just when running from the computer, even if I dont do anything to it

edit: it seems that the problem isn't in the framework, but is in the fact that, for some reason, every 1 to 4 days xcode decides to create a new provisioning profile and delete the old ones, which makes any app, anywhere, crash on launch with that error.

I'm using the automatic provision profile selection and the default iOS developer signing identity.

Comment: Have you tried removing the app's from you phone?

Comment: @Cing, yes, I already removed the failing apps, created new ones from scratch and reinstalled them. They all start crashing at the exact same time, regardless of when I last edited each one of them

Comment: Is this on multiple devices?

Comment: yes, @Paulw11. Regardless of the device I install the app on, they all crash at the same time (in all of the devices). Also, it doesn't matter from which mac I install the app, the problem is exactly the same

Comment: Did you tried clean?

Comment: yes, @Cing, i even created projects from scratch, and the problem persists

Comment: Sorry i can't help you

Comment: @RicardoSilva I also have exactly the same issue. Can you please elaborate how did you solve this issue?